# spark history server shutting down

Tags: apache-spark

I installed Spark and able to run Spark jobs.
however I can't access the spark history server.
when I start it, I can see the service is running:

[services running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXjSW.png)

but after few seconds the service is gone.
trying to access the web ui in port 18080 returning "site can't be reached"

Comment: Anything interesting in its stderr log file?

Comment: please also update the machine configuration where you set up the spark?

Comment: @mazaneicha I don't see any error, I just have the history server service disappear from the running services few seconds after starting it.

Comment: @NiteshSharma it's raspberry pi 4 with 8gb, running ubuntu 20.04.2
Spark version is 2.4.5 (also tried with 3.1.2 and didn't succeed)

Comment: @lc14 so you basically want us to guess? :) Perhaps you can set logging level to DEBUG and share the output?